# If statement in HTML using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS and I am displaying results using javascript `document.getElementById(bj).innerHTML = Result` 
in the HTML part I created table to display the result

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>subject1</th>
                <th>marks</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>mathematics</td>
                <td><p id="maths"> </p></td>
                
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>science</td>
                <td><p id="science"> </p></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Here I want to display the row if that id (`<p id="maths"> </p>`) has present any value otherwise it should hide the entire row

Thanks

Comment: So... What's the question?

Comment: What do you mean by value of `<p>` tag?

Comment: Do you want to hide it or do you want to not exist in the html ?

Comment: @Saren I want to hind the row if the marks for that subject are not available

Comment: @ManishKammar and I guess it's the same thing for id like math but also science ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kammar,

Since you mention that you are using `document.getElementById(bj).innerHTML = Result` for some part of your content, I will provide a "templating based" solution which works in a similar way. Note that this solution will require regenerating HTML if different "marks" changes value or become null.

The following HTML and javascript code will achieve your goals and has been tested in codepen.io. Make sure the javascript is run after the HTML is loaded. This can be done by just putting the javascript code in a `<script>` tag after the HTML portion

HTML Code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>subject1</th>
            <th>marks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>

</table>
```

javascript code:

```
var marks={"mathematics":null,"science":89,"history":92} //some example data
var generatedHTML = ""
var rowTemplate=`
        <tr>
            <td>{{subject}}</td>
            <td><p id="{{subject}}">{{mark}}</p></td>
        </tr>
    `
var tableBody=document.getElementById("tableBody")
for(var key in marks){
   if(marks.hasOwnProperty(key)){
       var subject = key;
       if (marks[subject])
       {
           var rowHTML=rowTemplate.replace(/\{\{subject\}\}/g,subject).replace(/\{\{mark\}\}/g,marks[subject]);
           generatedHTML+=rowHTML
       }
   }
}
tableBody.innerHTML=generatedHTML
```

I hope you can learn some things from the code.

If you want a very generalized and powerful solution to these types of problems, I advise learning **React.js**. React.js allows for *conditional rendering* (which is the nature of your problem), as well as handling DOM events and a host of other things.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function and use `getElementById` to either display it or hide it depending on results.

```
function toggleMathSection() {
  var x = document.getElementById("maths");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

All you'd really need to do is check the value and do an `If` statement and call this function to hide/show the row.

Also note that if you want to hide the entire row, you might want to give an ID or Class to the `<tr>` tag and use its Id to hide/show.

Comment: Lets hope what isnt null?

Comment: Which only happens when there is no element with the proper Id.

Comment: and so it's not compatible with the question and also this is not a good way of working, since the code became less easy to work with and you risk to have some problem for futurs implementations

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. You expect code to go missing or what do you mean?

Answer (score -2):

Give your row an id, like:

```
<tr id="result-row">
  <td>mathematics</td>
  <td><p id="maths"> </p></td>
</tr>
```

and change it's (CSS)-style from javascript, like:

```
document.querySelector('#result-row').style.display = '';
```

to show (empty string will revert it to the default value) and

```
document.querySelector('#result-row').style.display = 'none';
```

to hide it.

Comment: I really hop nothing here return null, else you will crash :P